# A simple/fast way to estimate distribution modality?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, data

Is there a simple and performant way to estimate whether an empirical distribution generated from a list of data is unimodal and if not (or is reasonably uniform and doesn't have modality at all), to estimate number of clear modes in it? Is there a native Mathematica dip test or an excess mass test, or basically anything that would estimate existence, count, and location of modes?

I know you can use R from Mathematica and run `dip.test`, but I'd rather not go that route if I can help it. I'm also aware of `FindDistribution[]`, but that's far from performant, and it estimated complete parameters. I'd like to get a fast yay/nay on existence of significant dips and peaks. I feel that the right solution will come from a clever use of `FindPeaks[]` or some other find max/min type functionality.

**Number and location(s) of modes:**
[image: number and locations of modes]

**Test for intensity of modality:**
(not "modularity", I borrowed the visual from another StackExchange thread and it came with the misprint)
[image: intensity of modality]

Comment: Peaks can be "in the eye of the beholder".  I'm assuming that you have random samples from some smooth probability distributions.  You could use `SmoothKernelDistribution` to estimate the probability distribution.  Then create equally-spaced values to plug into `FindPeaks`.  Maybe a bootstrap approach would get you some measure of the variability of the number and location of the peaks.  I certainly wouldn't use the heights of histogram bars as input to `FindPeaks`.   But what is the consequence of not getting the number of peaks correct?

Comment: I'm working with various healthcare data. Typically, not having a reasonably well-defined unimodal distribution (very close to a Weibull or Normal) means that the data is heterogeneous and a mixture of multiple confounding factors. E.g. having if you were to look at the number of visits by age, you'll see a disproportionately high number on the low end and another at the high end, because the facility has regional specialization in pediatric and geriatric care. If you compare patient age by gender, there's a modality @ 18-40 for women, which men do not have due to fertility-related visits...

Comment: ...I'm trying to understand several things: (1) are there multiple factors which a researcher should be looking into? (2) is there one or more anomalous peak(s) where a unimodal (likely normal) dist is expected? (3) can unimodal statistics be applied to a dataset, or should it be treated as a mixture model (without the computational cost of running it through `FindDistribution[]`)? (4) to use for simplifying computing posterior density region for Bayesian credible region estimation (MUCH simpler to find for a unimodal dist than for a multimodal one)

Comment: If you have multiple observations per patient (Patient X of age A has V visits), you don't want to fit histograms.  In those cases you might want something like Poisson regression.  And while I definitely have a bias:  it sounds like you need a statistician.

Comment: I'm aware of Poisson regressions and while I'm far from a statistician, I'm not totally naive in the subject either. Examples I gave above are "for instance" example. There would be numerous uses for figuring out PMF's modality.  Granted that "dips" are in the eye of the beholder, but that can be a parameter, modified by the researcher.

Comment: One of the main needs is to find anomalies in data distributions over very large number of correlations. So instead of taking one dataset of 2-5 variables and doing everything by hand, instead, the algorithm would automatically analyze distributions of tens of thousands of variables changing for a very large population (millions of patients, tens of millions of encounters, considering lab values, med dosages, pathology findings, etc.), doing so for a multitude of cohorts, comparing cohorts together automatically. So there ISN'T a "beholder". It should be reasonably automated.

Comment: Actual example: bimodality was detected in weight distribution, which didn't correlate to the age distribution. This shouldn't happen! The was flagged, and an error was found in the application where units where being saved incorrectly. So KG and LBS were occasionally both stored as the other one, creating very large or very small values for the age. While dwarfism and other conditions make that possible, the error was in excess of that, which is normal for the data. That extra bump in the data gave away the software bug.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't state things very well.  I'm not suggesting that dips and peaks are hallucinations.  What I didn't express very well is that there would need to be more specifics as to how you want to define a dip or peak.  For instance, the approach I suggested above will find a peak at an isolated point in a tail area.  What gets counted a dip or peak is what is important to your objectives.  No statistician can (or should) tell you what your objectives are.  But they might be helpful in constructing a concise and well-defined metric.

Comment: Ah. Got it. For my intended purposes, I think the drop in probability mass beyond X% compared to previous and next maximum peaks. E.g. diff of <5% between highs and lows (extreme tails notwithstanding), would indicate a uniform distribution. E.g. someone's BMI might fluctuate up or down by few kg, but without serious changes in weight (diet, disease, or pregnancies), it should resemble a wavy "flat" line. However, if there's a value surrounded by values of at least 6%+ lower than the maximum, this would be considered a peak, surrounded by dips.

Comment: Tail's end is considered a "dip" per se, since distributions could be a mixture of say Poisson with lambda 1 and Poisson with lambda 10, having a great mass at the lowest end, and virtually no mass at the high end, with a bump in the middle.

Comment: ...just one idea. Perhaps someone else has better ideas.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to see if Mathematica implements any of the known modality tests: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution#Statistical_tests
R, as mentioned in the question, implements Hartigans' dip statistic: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/diptest/versions/0.75-7/topics/dip.test